# Continuity on extended complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

If a function $f:\mathbb{C}^\infty \to \mathbb{C}^\infty$ and let $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}^\infty$. If we have that $\lim\limits_{z \to z_0} f(z) = f(z_0)$ then $f$ is continuous at $z_0$? For example:

1. if $f(2) = \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{z \to 2} f(z) = \infty$, then $f$ is continuous at $z_0 = 2$
2. if $f(\infty) = \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} f(z) = \infty$, then $f$ is continuous at $z_0 = \infty$

Are these 2 statements true? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. In general, given two topological spaces $(X,\tau)$, $(Y,\rho)$, a function $f:X\to Y$, a point $x_0\in X$ and some $L\in Y$, we say that $L$ is a limit of $f$ as $x\to x_0$ if and only if for all neighbourhoods $V$ of $L$ there is some neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $f[U\setminus\{x_0\}]\subseteq V$. With that definition, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $f(x_0)$ is a limit of $f$ as $x\to x_0$.

Comment: For the record, clearly your (2) does not satisfy the hypothesis $z_0\in \Bbb C$, but it would be true with $z_0\in\Bbb C^\infty$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Sorry. I've edited! Thanks for all!

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio but any $f:\mathbb{C}^\infty \to \mathbb{C}^\infty$ is continuous at $\infty$? Is $f(\infty)$ defined as $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)$?

Comment: No, it isn't. $\infty$ is a bona fide point of $\Bbb C^\infty$, therefore functions $f:\Bbb C^\infty\to X$ must be defined at $z=\infty$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio So can I have a function like $f:\mathbb{C}^\infty \to \mathbb{C}^\infty, f(z) = z, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(\infty) = 1$ for example that is not continuous at $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, you can${}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio So can you answer me at this question please? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4800075/1053101 . I don't understand from comments.

Comment: It's what user Jair Taylor said.