# Question about proof from Complex Made Simple (David C. Ullrich)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I have a question about Theorem 15.0.0 from Complex Made Simple (David C. Ullrich):

> If $\phi \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{D})$ is not the identity then one of the following holds: 
> (i) $\phi$ has exactly one fixed point in $\mathbb{D}$ and none on $\partial \mathbb{D}$; 
> (ii) $\phi$ has no fixed points in $\mathbb{D}$ and exactly one on $\partial \mathbb{D}$; 
> (iii) $\phi$ has no fixed points in $\mathbb{D}$ and exactly two on $\partial \mathbb{D}$.

In the proof he prove the corresponding statement for $\phi \in \text{Aut}(\Pi^+)$ (superior semiplan). We know that any $\phi \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{\Pi^+})$ has the form $\phi(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}, ad-bc =1$. He takes two cases: $c=0$ and $c\neq0$.
When $c \neq 0$, he says that $\phi(\infty) = \frac{a}{c} \in \mathbb{C}$. How he obtained that $\phi(\infty) = \frac{a}{c}$?

Edit: I think I got it. $\phi(z) = \frac{z(a + \frac{b}{z})}{z(c+\frac{d}{z})}=\frac{a+\frac{b}{z}}{c+\frac{d}{z}} \implies \phi(\infty)=\frac{a+0}{b+0} = \frac{a}{b}$. It's ok?

Comment: Well, $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} (az + b) / (cz + d) = \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} (a + b/z) / (c + d/z) = a/c.$

Comment: @JairTaylor, but from where I know that $\phi$ is continuous at $\infty$ and $\lim_{z \to \infty} \phi(z) = \phi(\lim_{z \to \infty}z) = \phi(\infty)$?

Comment: I believe $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \phi(z)$ is just the definition of $\phi(\infty)$.

Comment: But if I have a piecewise function, e.g. $f(z) = z, \, \, \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(z) = 0$ for $z = \infty$, then is not continuous at $z = \infty$ and I can't apply your formula.

Comment: I believe in this context it's assumed that the function would be extended to $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$ so that the result in meromorphic on the extended plane. There is a unique such extension when it exists. So the value at $\infty$ is determined, not an arbitrary choice. But to be sure, you need to consult the text to check what is meant by $f(\infty)$.

Comment: @JairTaylor so if we take this definition, we have that $f$ is always continuous at $\infty$?

Comment: Yes, I think you always set $f(\infty)$ so that $f$ is continuous at $\infty$. But again I would check the text to be sure.

Comment: Have you heard of the Riemann sphere ?

Comment: @mick yes. But in this textbook $f(\infty)$ don't have a definition. I know that on Riemann sphere $\infty$ is a point like all the others. This is why I'm asking

Comment: @MathLearner yeah it is. That is the context of the topic. Notice that these moebius functions are meromorphic at infinity.  This then makes an Aut.  And we can use l'hopitals rule to get the limit formally.